# Handle 47gb JSON File

Tags: python, json, large-data

I have a 47gb JSON file which has the following form

```
{
  "data": {
    "Key_A": {small JSON ~50mb},
    "Key_B": {small JSON ~50mb},
    "Key_C": {large JSON ~47gb}
  }
}
```

The exact structure and content of `file.data.Key_C` is unknown and I'd like to analyze it (e.g. how many `key:val`, get the size of the items, etc).

My idea was reading line by line unfortunately I am unable to: The following script was not able to terminate (I had to abort when monitoring the session memory usage).

```py
f = open(file_name, 'rb')
for line in f:
    if 'Key_C' in file_name.decode('cp1252'):  # Windows encoding
        break

f.close()
```

If the JSON is unindented (I do not know if that is the case) reading it line by line might not be feasible. Streaming char-by-char might be a solution. I am pretty much stuck here.

Comment: A streaming JSON parser? There are a few old questions about that e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560154/streaming-json-parser).

Comment: Why would indentation make *any* difference?

Comment: @ScottHunter I thought no indent would mean the whole JSON is in one line?

Comment: Indentation is a property of each individual line, not how *many* lines there are.